# Moving across locations

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

When can we move to different locations in Pathfinder ACG? We start the game already in a location. Can we move several times per turn? Say, explore once, move, explore by discarding something, move, etc?

Also, can we move only in our turn? If a player needs help on his combat, can we move in his turn to his location to play some card that requires being in the same location?

Finally, what happens when a location is closed? Do all players there instantly move to a new location? Or is the move done just when their turn starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which Pathfinder ACG game you are referring to. I will answer from Rise of the Runelords...but the rules are mostly the same for all of the games.

> When can we move to different locations in Pathfinder ACG?

The order of actions for a turn is:

1. give a card (to a player at your location)
2. move
3. explore
4. discard cards

You can do each one or zero times.

You may get extra explores, as you have mentioned, in many ways. There are a few powers & spells that allow you extra moves. They tell you when you can use them.

> Can we move several times per turn?

No. Unless you've used a spell or power that allows it.

> Also, can we move only in our turn?

Yes. Unless you've used a spell or power that allows it.

> If a player needs help on his combat, can we move in his turn to his location to play some card that requires being in the same location?

No. Unless you've used a spell or power that allows it.

> Finally, what happens when a location is closed? Do all players there instantly move to a new location?

No.

> Or is the move done just when their turn starts?

Yes.

The default answer to everything in Pathfinder ACG is that you can ONLY do what a card says you can do. No more and no less.  And of course, you can do what is explicitly defined in the rulebook.

I found these FAQs very helpful:

- Rise of the Runelords: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gk
- Skulls & Shackles: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gu
- Wrath of the Righeous: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1h4

Comment: *Give a card*? Where on the rules does it say that? We just take a card from our hands and give it someone else?

Comment: Page 8 of the rulebook has the full turn sequence listed (the 4 that I listed are included).    "You may give 1 card from your hand to another player at your location".

Comment: Also, when I said "unless you've used a spell or power that allows it", I should have said "unless you've played a card or used a power that allows it". There are items that allow movement as well...not just spells. Could be other card types, too (allies, perhaps?). Anyway...it's not limited to spells.